# Why doesn't netsplit riding work on single node networks?

Tags: network

I've been reading up on netsplit riding (a.k.a riding the split) and according to multiple sources, it's only a risk to multi server networks.

Now I understand that a netsplit occurs when a node disconnects from the IRC network, so a netsplit is not possible on a single server network as there is only one node.

But theoretically wouldn't an attacker be able to disconnect everyone from a single server network and acquire the op status? This technically wouldn't be riding the split but it would be very similar.

Answer (score 4):

You've basically answered your own question. The way I see it is that an attacker can disconnect everyone, including the attacker, by performing a denial of service attack or exploit a vulnerability in the IRC daemon/server.

While performing a denial of service, in theory the attacker could gain op in one or more channels by stopping the denial of service and then quickly connect to the IRC network.

However, there are also IRC operators that could easily get back the channel, especially since it's a small network, so global rules for specific networks do not apply.

Counter measurements would be to install (a) service(s) like Anope where people can register their nick(s) and/or channel(s) to prevent take overs.